# Kubernetes Ingress - How to rewrite all non-www traffic to www subdomain?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes Ingress resource where I'm trying to redirect all non-www traffic to www subdomain for url canonicalization. So all traffic on `example.com` should be rewritten to `www.example.com`. I can't seem to figure out how to use the [Ingress rewrite example](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/rewrite) properly to achieve this.

My Ingress (JSON format):

```
{
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "example-staging",
    "annotations": {
      "ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/",
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name": "example-static-ip"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "www.example.nl",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "example-service",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` is used for rewriting the request URI, not the host.

It looks like from your link you're using the nginx ingress controller. You can get the effect you want by adding a second `Ingress` for `example.nl` that uses the `ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation to add the 301.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "example-staging-wwwredir",
    "annotations": {
      "ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/",
      "ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet": "return 301 $scheme://www.example.nl$request_uri;"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "example.nl",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "example-service",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```