# GKE GCE Ingress redirect www to non-www

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, redirect, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to get the url [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to redirect itself to example.com while preserving everything about the original request in k8s 1.27.3

Is there any annotation available that can help for the redirection?

I was thinking if any annotation is enabled then simply set it to carry the redirection but it seems it is only present for nginx-ingress controller. I was also looking into this answer user slyfox [here] ([GKE GCE Ingress FrontendConfig redirect non-www to www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72241109/gke-gce-ingress-frontendconfig-redirect-non-www-to-www)) if it is possible to do it by simply adding an nginx sidecar container and add the server configuration from [here](https://medium.com/@alpercitak/redirect-nginx-www-to-non-www-543558213e1b). If anyone can guide in the process it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The annotation [ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md) is the target URI where the traffic must be redirected. It is used for rewriting the request URI, not the host  in nginx ingress controller.Please refer to the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407729/kubernetes-ingress-how-to-rewrite-all-non-www-traffic-to-www-subdomain?rq=3) for further information on redirection.

Comment: @Srividya I think that is not supported by GCE